# SSIS- Roll back delete commands

Tags: sql-server, ssis, transactions, etl, data-warehouse

I am using SSIS packages to daily refresh the data. Package logic is as follows,

1. Delete all rows in destination table
2. Insert full new data into destination table.

I am trying to find out ways to rollback delete if my insert fails. I tried using SSIS package transaction as below:

[image]

But now, after Delete SQL task is run , my package goes stuck for long time and does not respond. 
[image]

What is the recommended way for doing this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few techniques to consider here including some more complex ideas, but if we're looking at simpler ones, you could insert into a table with a different name but the same structure, and only if that works would you then swap it out somehow. One way of doing this is to use views for your access to tables, and then modify the view on success to use the table you've just inserted into.

It might not be the most elegant way, but it is one of the simpler ones to consider.

Comment: Rather than using a view, I'd recommend just rename the tables using sp_rename.  This is easily scriptable.

Answer (score 0):

Change the default of the Transaction Option property of the package to "Required" and make sure each object has that property set to "Supported" which is the default.

Additionally, you can minimize the transaction by doing the same thing with a sequence container around just your Execute SQL task and data flow.

FYI, I can't see pictures at work so I do not know what your package looks like.

Comment: There are more tasks than just two that OP has in mind. To achieve what he needs, he has to either set 'Required' for the package, 'Supported' for delete and insert tasks and 'NotSupported' for all other tasks, or, as you say, put the two tasks in question into a container and set the transaction option to 'Required' for the container (and of course Supported for tasks inside it which is the default setting)

Comment: @keithL sorry , i did notn realise i had wrong screenshot attached. My package already has Transacrtion= required. But then my package gets stuck because of my delete step. If i change the delete step with some insert or update step then transaction works perfectly

Comment: My Delete step and DFT step has transaction set to 'Supported'

Comment: instead of using the whole package try using just a sequence container for the transaction that you want to create.